# Помогите допилить решение задачи C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, олимпиада

Условие:
https://www.eolymp.com/ru/problems/7310

Мое решение:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;          /*  eolymp - 7310*/

int main()
{
    int bs, n;
    cin >> n >> bs;

    int ans = n * (n + 1) / 2;

    if ((-1. + sqrt(8. * bs + 1.)) / 2. == int((-1. + sqrt(8. * bs + 1.)) / 2.))
        ans -= 1;

    cout << ans;
    return 0;
}
```

Моя идея: если badStep(bs) не равен какому-либо члену арифметической прогрессии с разностью 1, то все нормально и все шаги мы можем нормально идти, т.е тогда просто выводим сумму элементов такой прогрессии. Если же нет, просто не делаем первый шаг, и тогда дальнейшими шагами уже точно не попадаем в bs, и ответом будет та же сумма, уменьшенная на 1.

> (-1. + sqrt(8. * bs + 1.)) / 2.

Вот это вот появилось из решения квадратного уравнения ni(ni + 1) = bs, где ni - номер какого-то члена прогрессии. Ну т.е. я проверяю, если при сумме элементов = bs, кол-во элементов - целое число, получается мы попадаем в bs и надо отнимать 1(чтобы не попадать)

Проблема: (https://www.eolymp.com/ru/submissions/11153820)
Почему то один тест не проходит, возможно какой-то случай-исключение, но я сколько ни думал, никак не могу понять где. Помогите пожалуйста )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Намек: а что если у вас `n == 3`, например, а `badStep` — пара тысяч? Но в прогрессию вписывающаяся?

Вот, на коленке...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, b;
    cin >> n >> b;
    int k = round((sqrt(1+8*b)-1)/2.);

    if (b > n*(n+1)/2) k = 0;
    else if (k*(k+1)/2 == b) k = 1;
    else k = 0;

    cout << n*(n+1)/2 - k;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Действительно что-то я недоглядел, ведь нужно еще проверять длину последовательности(и сравнивать с данной), в которую это мое bs входит...
Намек понят, так сказать)